# decompress ZIP with given encoding

Tags: encoding, zip, freebsd, unzip

I got ZIP file(s), which contains files, which filenames are in some encoding. Let's say I know encoding of those filenames, but I still dont know how to properly decompress them.

Here is example [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4444564/stackoverflow/gb18030.zip), it contains one file 
"【SSK字幕组】The Vampire Diaries 吸血鬼日记S06E12.ass"

I know used encoding is GB18030 (Chinese)

Question is - how to unpack that file in FreeBSD using unzip or other CLI utility to get proper encoded filename? I tried everything what I could, but result was never good. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work

```
unzip -O GB18030 gb18030.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [unzip-iconv](https://github.com/m13253/unzip-iconv).

Then, try [(from here)](http://utauarianna.altervista.org/tutorials/unzipping-japanese-encoded-archive/):

`UNZIP="-O YOURENCODING" unzip -x YOURFILE.zip`

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply unpack files with zip and then use `converters/convmv` to recode their names.